# Validations misfiring in a form with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a web app that saves a user's goals and tasks, where a user has_many goals, and a goal has_many tasks. When I try to save a goal and task together, I keep getting validation errors saying "Tasks goal can't be blank" and "Tasks content can't be blank," even though they clearly aren't. I'm certain the problem isn't with the actual form, but with the goal controller's 'new' or 'create' code, but whatever I try, I can't seem to get it right. Any ideas on why the validations for the task model are misfiring? I've been working on this issue for too long and I'm about to give up. I've included the goal controller, goal model, task model, and debug info. If you need to see any other code, let me know.

Goal Controller:

```
def new 
  @title = "New Goal"
  @goal = Goal.new
  @goal.tasks.build
end     

def create
  @user = current_user
  @goal = @user.goals.build(params[:goal])
  @task = @goal.tasks.build(params[:goal][:task])
  if @goal.save
    flash[:success] = "Goal created!"
    redirect_to user_path(@user) 
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Goal Model:

```
# Table name: goals
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id         :integer
#  content         :string(255)
#  completed       :boolean
#  completion_date :date
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#

class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :content, :completed, :completion_date
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 140 }

end
```

Task Model:

```
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  goal_id         :integer
#  content         :string(255)
#  occur_on        :date
#  recur_on        :string(255)
#  completed       :boolean
#  completion_date :date
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :content, :occur_on, :recur_on, :completed
  belongs_to :goal

  validates :goal_id, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 140 }

end
```

Debug Dump after an unsuccessful save:

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
authenticity_token: NF/vVwinKQlGAvBwEnlVX/d9Wvo19MipOkYb7qiElz0=
goal: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  content: some goal
  tasks_attributes: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
    "0": !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      content: some task
commit: Submit
action: create
controller: goals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with nested attributes.  You cannot validate the presence of the encapsulating model from the nested model (in your case, you cannot validate the presence of goal_id from Task).  When validations are run the goal is not yet saved, and thus has no id, so it is impossible to assign it.

You can either eliminate the validation that is causing the problem, or not use the built-in nested attributes.  In the latter case, you would need to add your own logic to first save the goal and then create any nested tasks.

Bummer, huh?  I wish someone would come up with a good solution for this...maybe I'll work on it if I ever get some free time.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of this line `@task = @goal.tasks.build(params[:goal][:task])`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, at least now I know it's not just my code that's messed up. I just removed the goal_id validation, but the content validation still doesn't pass. By removing the content validation, everything saves, including the goal and the task model, but the task model's content field is blank. And without the @task = @goal.tasks.build(params[:goal][:task]), the task model doesn't save. I'm still very new to rails, and I'm not exactly sure why I need it.

Comment: @grant You don't need it...in fact, that should be the cause of your blank content error.  That line is building another Task from a blank hash, thus that tasks will have blank content.  Try removing that line.

Comment: By the way, when I had this same problem the first time, I spent a couple hours scratching my head as to why I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: That makes sense, but I just got rid of that line, and the goal saves just fine, but the task model refuses to save at all now. This has been the loop I was stuck in for the last few days haha. If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them.

Comment: Wow, I finally figured it out! I checked out the server log and it said "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tasks_attributes". I just added ':attr_accessible :tasks_attributes' to my goal model and it worked! Thanks for your help @Wizard, I wouldn't have solved this without you!