# Rails 4: validating a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the validator for a nested attribute:

```
validates_numericality_of :rate, greater_than: 0, if: -> {self.user.is_tutor?}
```

where is_tutor is a boolean field in the parent form.

Despite many attempts, the validation doesn't seem to do what I'd like it to do. I would like it to take the params[:is_tutor] value that is being passed to the updated form, but my validator is always checking the value stored in the database.

How can I set the :if => to the params hash for the boolean value is_tutor? I've tried with params[:is_tutor] but that did not work.

I have also tried putting this in the parent:

```
validates_numericality_of :rate, greater_than: 0, if: :is_tutor?
```

This looks at the present value of :is_tutor, which is what I want. However, it does not find the :rate symbol, since it is a nested attribute.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post code from your controller?

Comment: Try using this to debug the problem, `validates_numericality_of :rate, greater_than: 0, if: -> { binding.pry }`

Comment: This logic needs to live in your controller (or some other layer between the controller and the model).  You should also think about security implications of relying on the value of a form field, which a user can change, even if hidden.

Comment: @MarekTakac my controller is quite empty...just a vanilla Devise application_controller.rb pretty much

Comment: @trev9065 thanks for that tip. I used binding.pry in my controller and found that the only place that param is getting passed is in Devise's update method. My update method looks like this now `def update; super; end` because it inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController. The value is being stored inside of **params[:user][:is_tutor]**. Is it possible to use this in the validator? Also, would doing so be a security risk??

Comment: Right so I am still unable to figure this out. I am not able to run the validation based on the checkbox. Shouldn't Rails make things like this simple? -_-

Comment: Can't you put the `binding.pry` in your model and then try to update it using the console or something?

Comment: From `binding.pry` I can only do `if: -> {self.user.is_tutor?}` to access that value, but that's the value in the db, not the one being passed in the form.

Comment: @trev9065 I found this answer on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603159/validations-misfiring-in-a-form-with-multiple-models/6603934#6603934
I think it's possible with attr_accessible in rails 3 but I'm not sure how to do it with Devise & Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

This should work although I didn't test it.

`validates_numericality_of :rate, greater_than: 0, if: -> (r) {r.user.is_tutor?}`

Comment: This doesn't work. It would if :rate did not live in a nested attribute. Since it lives in a nested attribute, r.user.is_tutor? reads from the db, where the value is set to true, so the validator never sees if the value being passed in the current form is false.

Comment: This is a bug with Rails 4, I just tried it on a Rails 3.2 app and it worked as expected (with the new user). It should be fixed soon.